# Why does Stack Overflow mark questions as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, new-users, post-ban

I am new to Stack Overflow. I just want to find out why questions are marked duplicate and lead to banning of asking future questions. For beginners it's not helpful because, while the solution might be the same for the problem, it is implemented differently as per the program - an implementation beginners cannot see unless helped. Yet such questions are marked duplicate and beginners cannot ask anymore.

Comment: A question being marked as duplicate doesn't lead to bans. Asking bad questions does. They're two very different things.

Comment: so my questions weren't of good quality that's what lead to Ban? because i formatted them correctly,and followed the rules

Comment: Did you google your problem? Did you explain it well? Neither of your currently visible questions would contribute strongly to a ban; I posit you have (possibly several) deleted questions that were downvoted.

Comment: Read more about bans here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584

Comment: No i am not currently banned,but am afraid to ask a new question because i got a warning that my current questions where not received properly and am in danger of a ban,And i explained as well as i could and i did google before asking,I have never deleted any questions am just worried about a ban if i ask another question

Comment: I looked at your 2 undeleted question.  I think you would benefit from reading [this article from the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because in both cases you posted large blocks of code and said basically said "I am getting this error, help me find my problem".  The act of creating a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" will actually help you solve your problems, especially problems caused by exceptions because it will help you figure out the problem code and may even get you to your solution.

Comment: Okay i understand,i was under the impression the more the cod,the clearer it is,i will read through the help center

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I am new to Stack Overflow.

Well then welcome.

> I just want to find out why questions are marked duplicate and lead to banning of asking future questions.

Questions are marked as duplicates, because there are already good answers available.

> For beginners it's not helpful because, while the solution might be the same for the problem, it is implemented differently as per the program - an implementation beginners cannot see unless helped.

As the old saying goes, give a man a fish and he eats for a day; teach a man to fish and he'll never go hungry.  As a beginner it's critical that you learn (at least) two things.

First, learn how to debug. Looking at your profile, I see that there are Java and Android tags on both your questions. Both have good debuggers available that let you step through your code line-by-line and see what's happening. Debugger use is not optional if you want to improve as a programmer.

Second, learn how to reduce a problem. Learn how to cut down your code into the minimum necessary to reproduce the error you see. Often this reduction will help you find the answer. (See also: [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging))

The answers that will help you grow the most as a programmer, are not of the form, "Change the i on line 20 to a b," but rather require you to make a conceptual jump. That is, to take knowledge of a solution to a slightly different problem, and use it to solve your own. Programming can be incredibly challenging and frustrating, but it also can be very rewarding.

Contrary to the sometimes stated opinion, those of us that answer questions, and especially those of us who come to Meta, enjoy helping people and leading them to a solution, but unfortunately time is limited, and we can't spend hours digging through every question that comes. There just aren't enough hours in a day. Closing questions as duplicates, generally helps point people in the right direction, and improves searchability for other people.

> Yet such questions are marked duplicate and beginners cannot ask anymore.

Beginners ask *lots* of questions here, and many (for some number of many) of them are well written and well reasoned. Questions closed as duplicates are one part of that, but remember that some of the questions that get closed as duplicates could also be closed for other reasons.

No one will get a question ban from one or two bad questions. (Obviously spam/abuse is the exception to the rule.)  Don't view a question ban as a punishment. It's the system (automated and humans combined) telling you to slow down, and think about what the core of your question is, and take some time to reflect on how to phrase your next question.

Answer (score 14):

In the end, the duplicates *are* helpful for beginners. Even if the duplicate question is worded slightly different, tailoring a solution to your needs *will* make you *understand* the solution and - in the end - a better programmer. Dumb copy-pasting answers *won't* help at all.